# What's the difference between INuiFusionColorReconstruction::IntegrateFrame and ProcessFrame?

Tags: kinect, 3d-reconstruction

I'm learning KinectFusion, hope to use it to build a reconstruction application for 3D print.

Currently i'm confused by [IntegrateFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.nuikinectfusioncolorvolume.inuifusioncolorreconstruction.integrateframe.aspx) and [ProcessFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn804510.aspx) method of INuiFusionColorReconstruction.

`ProcessFrame` has one more parameter named `maxAlignIterationCount`, does it mean that `ProcessFrame` will do integrate for multiple times while `IntegrateFrame` only do integrate one time? Since ProcessFrame also only take one reference frame, what's the benefit to do integrate for multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's website:

"...the ProcessFrame function in the INuiFusionReconstruction interface... encapsulates the camera tracking (AlignDepthFloatToReconstruction) and the data integration step (IntegrateFrame) in one function call to be easier to call and more efficient as all processing takes place on the GPU without upload and readback for the individual steps as would occur when calling separately."

[Kinect for Windows 1.7, 1.8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn188670.aspx)